# Difference between Elman, Hopfield & Hemming Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks

What is the main difference between Elman, Hopfield & Hemming Recurrent Neural Networks?

Python Neurolab Library examples:

- [Elman Recurrent Neural Network](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newelm.html)
- [Hopfield Recurrent Neural Network](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newhop.html)
- [Hemming Recurrent Neural Network](https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/ex_newhem.html)

I properly understand the main difference of Hopfield Network:

> The Hopfield network is of historic interest although it is not a
>   general RNN, as it is not designed to process sequences of patterns.
>   Instead it requires stationary inputs. It is a RNN in which all
>   connections are symmetric. *Wikipedia*

But the other two is missing for me.

Comment: You need to give a lot more detail. Exactly what part of the definitions is unclear to you? Why do you think they are the same?

Comment: @vonbrand Obviously I don't have a good understanding about these different examples. Could you list the main differences? I can't say any type of difference because I'm not the best about neural networks as you can see I'm trying.

Comment: We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question what you've tried in the question.  If you haven't spent some time searching and reading about each of those to learn how each works yet, that would be a good thing to do before asking.  If you've already done that and couldn't find anything, you can tell us where you looked.  If you've done that and found resources, do you have any thoughts? any more specific questions?

Comment: @D.W. I saw hundreds of question that are asking for difference between algorithms in this site. I can't understand that what is wrong with this question. I made my research and I ended up with these samples that I share as links in my question. But I have failed to understand the distinction of these algorithms.